# Media query canceling other media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[image: an example of max-width: 960 canceling other media query blocks]

I'm confused because the logo should be hidden if width is less than 748px. However all sizes below 960px width ***show*** the logo.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post your code... Not a photo of your screen taken on your phone...

Comment: a photo of your monitor taken by a camera is absolutely amazing but unfortunately we need to see how your css is defined with an example

Comment: Ok, guys, no need to be harsh. I didn't see an error in the code. In fact, the code specifically for the .logo can be seen in the image.  I'll post the code in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In the screenshot of the screen) I see that the `max-width: 768px` media query is declared *before* `max-width: 960px` which is incorrect. Media queries that only use `max-width` should be sorted descending. Let us assume that you declare media queries in this order:

1. `(max-width: 768px)`
2. `(max-width: 960px)`

If your screen is 400px wide then both media queries will match the condition. In this case the media query block declared later wins.

Solution:

Sort your max-width rules descending (larger widths first).

Or use mutually exclusive media query blocks such as this:

- `(min-width: 961px)`
- `(min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 960px)`
- `(max-width: 768px)`

In this case order does not matter.

Comment: I thought of this. Hadn't tried though. You're right, I have the widths declared from smaller to bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .flicker-example {display: none !important}
}
```