# Advantages to using max-width as well as min-width in sequential media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, breakpoints

In a case where there are a clear series of breakpoints and related media queries, with each media-query altering the same property(s), is there any advantage to adding `max-width` values as well as `min-width` values?

For example is there any advantage to using:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 599px) {
   color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
   color: blue;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
   color: green;
}
```

Instead of just:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
   color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
   color: blue;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
   color: green;
}
```

To clarify, I understand that I can target a range by adding a min and max width, but I'm referring to situations where breakpoints are sequential and based on width. Given that the next value in the sequence will override (trump) the previous, is there any reason to explicitly declare a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying both `min-width` and `max-width` allows you to create blocks of rules that are *mutually exclusive*. The advantage is that you can specify the media queries in any order.
The disadvantage is that you need to repeat the CSS rules more often. Example:

```css
/* order of media queries does not matter */
@media (max-width: 299px) {
    #section-1 { display: none; }
    #section-2 { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    #section-1 { display: block; }
    #section-2 { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #section-1 { display: block; }
    #section-2 { display: block; }
}
```

Specifying only `min-width` or `max-width` allows you to create blocks of rules that can *cascade* across multiple breakpoints. The advantage is that you can write CSS rules inrementally with minimal repetition. The disadvantage is that the media queries need to be sorted ascending (for min-width) or descending for (max-width), otherwise [you run into WTFs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27228013/87015). Example:

```css
/* mobile first */
#section-1 { display: none; }
#section-2 { display: none; }
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    #section-1 { display: block; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #section-2 { display: block; }
}
```

```css
/* desktop first */
#section-1 { display: block; }
#section-2 { display: block; }
@media (max-width: 599px) {
    #section-2 { display: none; }
}
@media (min-width: 299px) {
    #section-1 { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: I think your answer for linked Q is better than mine for *this*.

Answer (score 1):

> From reading many industry blogs and even blog posts that I have
>   written myself, we generally provide samples with just two conditions:
>   screen and a max-width. For example:
>
> ```
> @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {...}
> ```
>
> This statement would include a screen (monitor or device) AND any
>   width less than 640px. Confusing right? Especially considering that in
>   our recent responsive email templates, we use a combination of two
>   breakpoints. For example:
>
> ```
> @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {...}
> @media only screen and (max-width: 479px)  {...}
> ```
>
> I didn't realize it at the time but in the example above, the second
>   media query actually trumps the first due to standard CSS inheritance
>   rules. By rights, the first triggers any device with a width less than
>   640px and the second triggers any device with a width less than 479px.
>   So if you truly want to trump the first, you need to make sure that
>   you overwrite all CSS properties under the second condition.

~[SOURCE](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width)

---

The '`device width`' that is returned is based on the orientation of the device. It's not based on the highest 'possible dimension' that the device can support in any orientation.

Again, the term 'max-width' is what led to my initial confusion here. Some devices return a different value depending on orientation and/or zoom level and others return the same value. Either way, there's only one 'width' value returned at any given time, it's not based on a range of values.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. I'm not asking what `min-width` and `max-width` do or mean.

Comment: No, you were (IMO) asking 'why use them both'. This (i feel), gives a general overview of why, since it means you can apply them by using ranges, instead of 'under xyz px' or 'over abc px'

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of having max-width is that you don't have to override styles later.  In the below example the styles for the 600px-999px range can be styled as wanted, without worrying about having to override the css from the smaller media query. This wouldn't be the case with the alternative cascade of Media Queries.  It depends how you prefer to do it.

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 599px) {
   h1 {
       color: blue;
       font-size: 40px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    h1 {
       font-size: 10px;
       }
}
```

Also it will be easier to debug without lots of overrode styles being crossed out in the browser developer tools.